# Custom metadata having field of type picklist and want to fetch that picklist field value of that custom metadata into LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-metadata

Please give me an idea on how to get the custom metadata field picklist values into lwc without using apex

Answer (score 1):

I think we cannot achieve this because in **getPicklistValues** ui Adapter recordTypeId is mandatory and in metadata we dont have any recordTypes.

> @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$RecordTypeId',
> fieldApiName: ... })

Comment: Okk but i want to achieve this scenario any other idea please

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know why you don't want to use apex. If you really don't want
> to use apex and there are not too many values and no possibility of
> change in values in future, then you can hardcode these in your
> component only.

You can go with apex. Because now you can get metadata without querying.
You can refer this document for help - [Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_metadata_types.htm)